# Why can I not import Appium if it's in my Gradle dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-14

I am using Intellij Community Edition with Gradle for the build.

here is my build.gradle deps:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4', 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-devicefarm-gradle-plugin:1.2'
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:4.0.0'
    classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:<latest>"
}
```

When I try to do import any of the appium stuff from io. Intellij says it isn't there. Even stranger in wy External Libraries there are numerous Gradle: libraries, but no Library for Appium.

I suppose Appium isn't a library, but I have tried both complie and testCompile and with neither one can I import any appium namespaces.

```
import io.appium.java_client.functions.AppiumFunction;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
```

these come up as not found in both my src and test folders. On the other hand I can import cucumber no problem.

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
```

the 2 above work and intellij will compile with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using this `dependency` in my test and it works fine. Could you please try the below. Make sure you **`rebuild`** the project after changing the `dependency`

```
dependencies{
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client
  compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '5.0.4'
}
```

Comment: By run you mean click on build.gradle and run it?

Comment: Yeah.
If you are getting notification 'gradle projects need to be imported' make sure you select 'Import Changes'

Comment: Ok will give it a try

Comment: it worked but my gradle classpaths threw an error. I removed them but any idea why I am getting: Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.amazonaws:aws-devicefarm-gradle-plugin:1.2]

Comment: As a temporary fix I would suggest you to download the aws-devicefarm-gradle-plugin.jar files and add the dependencies manually 

Project Right Click - Option > Module Settings > Modules > Dependencies: Here you can add the jar file that you have downloaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157195/discussion-between-yashwant-das-and-liminal18).

Answer (score 3):

Similarly, if you have your tests in androidTest, you can import like this:

```
androidTestImplementation 'io.appium:java-client:5.0.4'
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day, Almost all examples are with 'compile' so i automatically changes it to implementation, after 6 hours of struggle this answer saved me. Thanks again